# Trying to match each row in df1 with multiple other rows in df1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, tuples

So I am trying to figure out how to speed this operation up. Currently, the real dataset, takes about an hour to iterate over (~50,000 columns in df1 and df2), which doesn't seem very practical. Anyone have any suggestions? I.e pandas vectorization, pandas conditionals etc?

Basic operation: look at each row in df1, and compare to each row in df2. If the agent_id matches and the df1 'created_at_email' date is greater than or equal to the df2 'created_at' date, pull that row. Max rows allowed to pull is 4 for each row in df1 EDIT: ordered by most recent dates first.

Sample DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 
                    'agent_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7], 
                    'created_at_email': ['1/5/2020', '1/6/2020', '1/8/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/4/2020', '1/7/2020', '1/2/2020']
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 
                    'agent_id': [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                    'created_at': ['1/4/2020', '1/5/2020', '1/6/2020', '1/9/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/4/2020']
                   })
```

Code (needs to be sped up):

```
# pre-sorting order created at column so function will iterate from most recent to least recent orders.
df2 = df2.sort_values(['created_at'], ascending=False)



# note: super not optimized
obj = []
for row in df1.itertuples():
    count = 0
    for row2 in df2.itertuples():
        if row[2] == row2[2]:
            if row2[3] <= row[3]:
                if count < 4: # returns the first 4 entries
                    c = [row2[3], row[3], row2[2], row[2], row[1], row2[1]]
                    obj.append(c)
                    count = count + 1
```

Output: (what it should look like)...

 note: df1 can have multiple of the same agent_id and so can df2.

 note: dates on right are greater than or equal to, dates on left.

 note: unique_ids are just for checking if everything lines up.

```
cols: created_at, created_at_email, agent_id, agent_id, unique_id, unique_id 

[['1/5/2020', '1/5/2020', 1, 1, 'a', 'b'],
 ['1/4/2020', '1/5/2020', 1, 1, 'a', 'a'],
 ['1/4/2020', '1/5/2020', 1, 1, 'a', 'g'],
 ['1/3/2020', '1/5/2020', 1, 1, 'a', 'f'],
 ['1/6/2020', '1/8/2020', 3, 3, 'c', 'c'],
 ['1/3/2020', '1/3/2020', 1, 1, 'd', 'f'],
 ['1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', 1, 1, 'd', 'e']]
```

Thanks,

Comment: you could create a hash from the agent_id and save the rows in a associative array with hash(agent_id) as the key and all the rows that match that hash as the value. That way you'd only have to compare each row to the rows in the assiciative array with the same hash.

Comment: 50'000 columns or rows ?

Comment: 50k rows for df2 and df1 is around 50k rows as well. columns wise they're around 8-10 cols each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `merge` would be faster. I'm not sure about merging two 50k dataframes though:

```
(df1.assign(row=np.arange(len(df1)))          # record the row number in `df1`
    .merge(df2, on=['agent_id'])
    .query('created_at_email >= created_at')  # select rows with greater creat_at_email
    .groupby('row').head(4)                   # select max 4 rows for each row in df1
)
```

Output:

```
   unique_col_x  agent_id created_at_email  row unique_col_y created_at
0             a         1         1/5/2020    0            a   1/4/2020
1             a         1         1/5/2020    0            b   1/5/2020
3             a         1         1/5/2020    0            e   1/2/2020
4             a         1         1/5/2020    0            f   1/3/2020
9             d         1         1/3/2020    3            e   1/2/2020
10            d         1         1/3/2020    3            f   1/3/2020
12            c         3         1/8/2020    2            c   1/6/2020
```

Comment: I think you don't need `row`, can't you `groupby('unique_col_x')`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny totally, if the values are unique as indicated by the name. I was being cautious :-).

Comment: I think it’s usually referred to as self-merge and query.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for. Just one edit: I forgot to mention that I would like to pull the 4 most recent, keyword "recent". But anyway, tested it out on the real data and it works. Like 16,666.67 times faster (total run-time 413ms). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after:

The code merges df1 and df2, filters based on the dates, creates a cumulative count, and keeps only rows where the counter is less than 4.

```
(
    df1.merge(
        df2.assign(agent_id_right=df2.agent_id.astype("Int64")),
        on="agent_id",
        how="left",
        suffixes=("", "_right"),
    )
    .query("created_at_email >= created_at")
    .sort_values("created_at", ascending=False)
    .assign(counter=lambda x: x.groupby(list(df1.columns), sort=False).cumcount())
    .loc[
        lambda x: x.counter.lt(4),
        [
            "created_at_email",
            "created_at",
            "agent_id",
            "agent_id_right",
            "unique_col",
            "unique_col_right",
        ],
    ]
    .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
)


  created_at_email  created_at  agent_id  agent_id_right    unique_col  unique_col_right
0   2020-01-05     2020-01-04      1           1             a             a
1   2020-01-05     2020-01-05      1           1             a             b
2   2020-01-05     2020-01-03      1           1             a             f
3   2020-01-05     2020-01-04      1           1             a             g
4   2020-01-08     2020-01-06      3           3             c             c
5   2020-01-03     2020-01-02      1           1             d             e
6   2020-01-03     2020-01-03      1           1             d             f
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This code also works for my problem. Upvoted!